In Excel, can i mass modify formulas so that they adapt to a new format the source sheet was modified to?
I have a sheet in Excel that has many formulas and it gets the necessary inputs from a sheet called "inputs". Someone else is in charge of maintaining this "input" sheet.
Recently, the format (title and subtitles position, mainly) was altered and now all my formulas are wrong
I need all the formulas in my sheet to reference 2 rows below what they used to. That is, the cell A1 used to reference cell AD315 from "input" A2 referenced AD316 and so on. Under the new format A1 should reference AD313, A2 should reference AD314 and so on. The problem is that there are around a thousand references and changing them 1 by one would take way too long.
Is there a way to make all the references 2 rows lower without doing it 1 by 1?
I´ve been updating cell by cell but it is taking way too long.

Change one then copy/paste down the column? (you can paste into the whole column at once)

Your question says it needs to reference 2 cells below where it did, but you explained it's actually needs to reference 2 cells above where it was? But you could simply reference the first formula to the correct cell, then while selecting the same cell (A1), in the bottom-right of the cell border you can click the box and drag the formula down. Double-clicking this box will auto-fill the formula down to the bottom of your range.

@MarkS. thank for noticing that. i ment lower in the numerical sense, since 313<315 but i see how that could be a bit misleading.
regarding the second point, i cant just drag my formulas because each formula has some ad hoc elements that dont work correctly when doing the dragging.

@cybernetic.nomad i  tried that but the formulas have some elements that are included/excluded on a case by case basis so doing it once and copying doesnt work correctly.

@FernandoTorrero if there's cell by cells changes that need to be made is that an adjustment that can happen in a different part of the formula? You could use =formulatext() to get the formulas for each cell and try to change the string and bring those texts back to formula.

Try the following kludge: 1) Select cells AD3:AD1000 (or until the end of the data in the column) 2) COPY the range and PASTE it in a separate workbook 3)CUT the same range. 4) Select cell AD1 and PASTE (this will paste in AD1:AD998 and the formulas will "follow" the new position). 5) Select the column you pasted in the other workkbook and paste it in AD3:AD1000 to get the data back inthe proper place

After taking a back-up copy of the file I usually use a simple Find/Replace to update formula.  You just have to be careful - if you had =SUM(A3:A9) you can't just say update A3 to A5 as it would capture A3, A30 - A39, A300-A399, etc.  But you can update it from (A3: to (A5:.

If you have Excel 365, there is a novel way to fix this once and forever. You can use MAP() to bulk run one single formula over a range of cells at once.
Suppose your range is AD315:AD1315. And your formula is, let's say, =ABS(AD315).
New universal formula is:
=MAP(AD315:AD1315,LAMBDA(x,ABS(x)))
This formula will take your range, then one by one take every cell (x), use it in formula inside LAMBDA() and return the same sized range of results.
If your colleague decides to move cells around again, just edit the range reference inside MAP() once, and it will run like before.
